# Using CDK to grant permissions to Dead Letter Queue on SNS Topic Subscription

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set up an SNS topic, with a subscription to a Queue. I want to put a Dead Letter Queue onto to the SNS Subscription.

This deploys OK, however in the AWS console, when I open the subscription, I see the error "Couldn't check Amazon SQS queue permissions. Make sure that the queue exists and that your account has permission to read the attributes of the queue".

Do I need to somehow grant write permission for `SNSTopic` to `TopicDLQ`?

```
export class SNSToSQSConstruct extends Construct {
    public readonly TopicDLQ: IQueue
    public readonly SQSQueue: IQueue
    public readonly SNSTopic: ITopic

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        this.TopicDLQ = new Queue(this, `${id}_TopicDLQ`, {
            visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
        });

        this.SQSQueue = new Queue(this, `${id}_Queue`, {
            visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
        });

        this.SNSTopic = new Topic(this, `${id}_Topic`, {
            fifo: false, // fifo support 300tps, standard support almost unlimited
            topicName: id,
        });

        var subscription = this.SNSTopic.addSubscription(new SqsSubscription(this.SQSQueue, {
            rawMessageDelivery: true,
            deadLetterQueue: this.TopicDLQ
        }));
        
        // error Subscription is not IGrantable
        //this.TopicDLQ.grantSendMessages(subscription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with `addToResourcePolicy`

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { IQueue, Queue } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs'
import { ITopic, Topic } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns'
import { SqsSubscription } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns-subscriptions'
import { ServicePrincipal, PolicyStatement, Effect} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'

export class SNSToSQSConstruct extends Construct {
    public readonly TopicDLQ: IQueue
    public readonly SQSQueue: IQueue
    public readonly SNSTopic: ITopic

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        this.TopicDLQ = new Queue(this, `${id}_TopicDLQ`, {
            visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
        });

        this.SQSQueue = new Queue(this, `${id}_Queue`, {
            visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
        });

        this.SNSTopic = new Topic(this, `${id}_Topic`, {
            fifo: false, // fifo support 300tps, standard support almost unlimited
            topicName: id,
        });

        var subscription = this.SNSTopic.addSubscription(new SqsSubscription(this.SQSQueue, {
            rawMessageDelivery: true,
            deadLetterQueue: this.TopicDLQ
        }));
        
        this.TopicDLQ.addToResourcePolicy(
            new PolicyStatement({
              effect: Effect.ALLOW,
              principals: [new ServicePrincipal('sns.amazonaws.com')],
              actions: ["sqs:SendMessage"],
              resources: [this.TopicDLQ.queueArn],
              conditions: {
                ArnEquals: {
                  "aws:SourceArn": this.SNSTopic.topicArn,
                },
              },
            })
          );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I learnt something about adding respource policies. Interestingly, the error message on the Topic Subscription ("Couldn't check Amazon SQS queue permissions...") is still there. This got me wondering if the error was incorrect. I deleted the queue linked to the subscription and posted a message. It appeared in the topic's DLQ as I would have hoped. If wonder if the error is being incorrectly shown, or refers to something else.